# How to map a list of Strings with Hibernate XML file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I'm trying to map a list of String using Hibernate XML mapping files. My class is the following:

```
public class Historic {
    private String id;
    private String resolution;
    private List<String> names;
    private List<Score> scores;
    private String base;
    private List<Grade> grades;
}
```

I read in the documentation that I should be using the `<element>` tag, but I don't know how I'm going to reference the specific attributes from the `Historic` class.

I think that it could be something like:

```
<class name="Historic" table="HISTORIC">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="resolution" type="string" column="resolution" />

    <element
        name="names"
        column="names"
        type="string"
    />

    ...

</class>
```

Is that right?

Comment: you can't directly do it in a single table, need a mapping first to other table.

Comment: you can do it but it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as follows:

```
<list name="names" table="names">
  <key column="name_id"></key>
  <index column="seq"></index>
  <element column="names" type="string"></element>
</list>
```

For further details take a look at https://achieversnitin.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/hibernate-collection-mapping-list/.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you've two table (parent and children)
you should do something like this -> in your case for grades, scores etc. you should define another tables.

here is an example of XML mapping in hibernate

```
<class name="Parent" table="Parent">
  <id name="parentId" column="id" type="integer" /> <!-- TODO: specify generator -->
  <property name="parentName" type="string" column="name" />
  <bag name="childs" table="Children" inverse="true">
    <key column="parent_id" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="Child" table="Children">
  <id name="childId" column="id" type="integer" /> <!-- TODO: specify generator -->
  <property name="childName" type="string" column="name" />
  <many-to-one name="parent" column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

but for List you can use `@ElementCollection annotation` too.
like this :

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="Nicknames", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
@Column(name="nickname") // nickname is the name of String field.
public List<String> getNicknames() { ... }
```

to get more info about collection : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues

I hope this helps you.

Comment: in above mapping, every parent has one or many child but each child has only one parent.